# HTML & CSS, not able to center horizontally with margin auto

Tags: html, css

I have problem with vertically centering the element in the navigation bar on my page. This is my code:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
header {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 50px;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" alt="logo"></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

My question is why the `div` element is not centered in the `header`, since in the CSS code the top and bottom margins of the `div` element are set to `auto`, and that's what I do to center vertically.

Comment: `margin: auto` to the `Y`-axis only works inside Flexbox and CSS-Grid. But you apply it to the flex container in your case. Properly better though to use `align-items` or `justify-content` depending on your `flex-direction` to center the content vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#values), you can't center a normal element horizontally with `margin: auto`:

> `auto`: The browser selects a suitable margin to use. For example, in certain cases this value can be used to center an element.

> To center something horizontally in modern browsers, you can use `display: flex;` `justify-content: center`.

Or you can simply add `display:grid` on your `header`, the container, and `margin:auto` works for horizontal alignment as well, cause then the `div` inside will become a `grid-item`, which is more flexible than a normal `div`. Like so:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
header {
  display:grid;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 50px;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" alt="logo"></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: or use Flexbox. with Flexbox he could get rid of the unnecessary `div` and use the header to align the items along the cross and side axis at the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

`margin: auto` to the `Y`-axis only works inside Flexbox and CSS-Grid. But you apply it to the flex container in your case. Properly better though to use `align-items` or `justify-content` depending on your `flex-direction` to center the content vertically.

In your case it would be way easier to simply remove the div as wrapper and apply the flexbox to the `header` itself and then vertically center the element with `align-items: center`:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
header {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" alt="logo"></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
header {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 50px;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" alt="logo"></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Vertically cetner using ->  align-items: center

Comment: but you must set a height for the div